# Is there a user stats plugin available?

Tags: users, plugins, control-panel

I am looking for a plugin or simple method that can add some stats to the User Admin. We have a membership site running for a client and it would be good to add either a count to the sidebar User Groups filters (eg "Users (11)") or a dashboard widget of basic stats.

Has anyone added this already, or used something suitable?

Answer (score 2):

Until the plugin store officially becomes a thing, [Straight up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins) has got the most curated list of plugins available for Craft at the moment.

I'm not seeing anything like you're describing for users, but it is definitely something a plugin should be able to handle.

Comment: Thanks Brad - I had looked there first - but nothing too developed for User management. We'll see what we can add ourselves for now.